# Organising factor based on two variables in R using fct_reorder2() from forcats package

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, forcats

From the table below, I would like to organise the factor levels of lineage based on the IDs in the two other columns. These IDs represent the ordered medians of two different variables I would like to sort by.

Example data:

```
# A tibble: 42 x 4
   lineage    lineage_sub_subtype      id_lss  id_l
   <chr>      <fct>                     <int> <int>
 1 lymphocyte b_cell_mediastinal_large      3    23
 2 lymphocyte b_cell_mantle_cell           17    23
 3 lymphocyte b_cell_mantle_cell           17    23
 4 lymphocyte b_cell_burkitt               21    23
 5 lymphocyte b_cell_burkitt               21    23
 6 lymphocyte b_cell_burkitt               21    23
```

I have tried to organise the factor levels by using `fct_reorder2()`. This organises the lineage_sub_subtype by `id_l` but does not order these by `id_lss`.

```
plt_data = data %>%
  mutate(lineage_sub_subtype = fct_reorder2(.f = lineage_sub_subtype, 
                               id_lss, 
                               id_l,
                               .desc = F))
```

Using this code, "b_cell_burkitt" comes before "b_cell_mediastinal_large" in my factor levels.

Am I misusing `fct_reorder2()`? How can I achieve what organising by my factor levels by two variables.

I am currently plotting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCm6c.jpg) (excerpt from larger graph) but would like to have each group (lineage) organised in descending median order.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: is the order correct in the rows of `data`? just do `factor(lineage_sub_subtype, unique(lineage_sub_subtype))`... translate that to tidy verse if you must

Comment: @rawr doh.. thanks so much. The answer was sat right in front of me!